# How to make global work in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, global

This snippet works as expected when run as a normal php web page.

```
<?php
  $foo = 123;

function whatever ()
{
  global $foo;
  echo "FOO = $foo<br/>";
}

whatever ();
?>
```

The output is

```
FOO = 123
```

But putting the exact same code in a drupal basic page gives this output

```
FOO =
```

PHP is obviously working, but globals does not.
I'm a noob with drupal, but I know php. I have googled this problem but found nothing relevant.

Why is it not working in drupal?
How do I make it work?
Please don't answer with, you should not use global!

Comment: How do you put this code to Drupal basic page? Did you create a module with this code and added it?

Comment: Drupal is written in PHP, it doesn't (and can't) do anything to stop you using globals. Drupal actually makes [extensive use of globals](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/7). I'd suggest moving your code out of the PHP filter (which uses `eval()` and is obviously causing problems) and into a custom module where this won't be an issue. See [Drupal 7 module development](https://drupal.org/node/1849934)

Comment: user4035, I click content - add content - basic page and set Text Format to PHP code. Clive, do you mean that putting php code in a basic page is using eval() to execute the php?

Comment: I just tested that the above code also works when executed in the eval() function in a normal php page (not drupal).

Answer (score 1):

Further experiments showed that this code in a Drupal php page works.

```
<?php
  global $foo;  // This trick makes it work
  $foo = 123;

function whatever ()
{
  global $foo;
  echo "FOO = $foo<br/>";
}
whatever ();
?>
```

The first "global" statement should not be needed, but seems to make it work. Also changing the first two lines to

```
$GLOBAL ["foo"] = 123;
```

is working.

Hope this can be helpful.